# Empty data was able to be stored to the Database in CakePHP even if "Not Null" had been specified

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I was doing some self learning on CakePHP 1.26 with Mysql 5.
I got a simple table with only one field and had applied "Not Null" to this field.
This field in the table was corresponding to a Input text box in a HTML form.
I tried not to enter anything into the Input text field, and then
I saw that empty data was able to be stored into the Table even if "Not Null" had been applied to this field.

I am confused of this result.
Could you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably storing an empty string.  An empty string ('') is not the same as a null.

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between "null" and "blank".  If you try `SELECT * FROM your-table WHERE your-not-null-column IS NULL`, do you get anything back?  If you try `SELECT * FROM your-table WHERE your-not-null-column = ''`, what do you get?